# Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: questions Filename: views/quiz.php

Tags: codeigniter

```
 **view**

    <?php foreach($questions as $row){ ?>

    <?php $ans_array = array($row->choice1,$row->choice2,$row->choice3,$row->answer);
    shuffle($ans_array);?>

    <p><?=$row->quizID?>.<?=$row->question?></p>

    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?>"> <?=$ans_array[0]?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?>"> <?=$ans_array[1]?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?>"> <?=$ans_array[2]?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?>"> <?=$ans_array[3]?><br>

    <?php } ?>

    </div>
```

**controller**

```
public function quest ()
    {
    $this->Model_students;  
    $this->data['questions']=$this->Model_students->quest();
    $this->load->view('quest',$this->data);
    }

    public function quiz ()
    {

    $this->load->view('quiz');
    }
```

**model**

```
public function quest()
    {
     $this->db->select("quizID,question,choice1,choice2,choice3,answer");
     $this->db->from("quiz");

     $query = $this->db->get();

     return $query->result();

     $num_data_returned = $query->num_rows;

     if ($num_data_returned < 1)
     {
       echo "there is no data in the db";
       exit();
     }


    }
```

after submitting this i get 2 errors;
1. Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: questions

Filename: views/quiz.php

Line Number: 14
2.everity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/quiz.php

Line Number: 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `$this`

```
$data['questions']=$this->Model_students->quest();
$this->load->view('quest',$data);
```